# Excel VBA Chart - Set labels of a graph to red if contains "Parenthesis"?

Tags: excel, vba

[update]: Final code used at the end of my question.

My problem refers to a graph customization in Microsoft Excel using VBA.

I'm trying to customize the label colors of my graph to **red color if the label contains a parenthesis** and **set to black otherwise**.
Find the graph below for reference (it has 4 labels).
[![graph][1]][1]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/B64Rjv8/2019-04-26-13h09-54.png))</sub>

**The desired result** will look like this:

[image: graph]

The code I've reached so far based on other examples, but without reaching my goal.

```
Sub Labels_graph_Test()

Dim Qrts As Series

Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Q_Graph")
Set Qrts = ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

For i = 1 To 4

     With Qrts.Points(i).DataLabel

     If InStr(1, currentcell, "(*") Then With Selection.Font.Color = vbRed
     Else: Selection.Font.Color = vbBlack

     End If   

Next i

End Sub
```

This code is not working and is giving the "Compile Error: End if without block if".

Please don't tell me to use conditional formatting because in this situation the labels are coming from cells so the conditional formatting doesn't work.

Big thank you in advance

Let me know in case something isn't clear

Best regards,
Martim Pinto

Final Code:

(for more insights, check the answer of Luuklag and FreeMan - both gave very useful insights and explanations)

```
Sub Labels_graph_Test()

Dim Qrts As Series

Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Q_Graph")
Set Qrts = ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

    For i = 1 To 4
        With Qrts.Points(i).DataLabel
    
            If Left(.Text, 1) = "(" Then
                .Font.Color = vbRed
            Else
                .Font.Color = vbBlack
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzA82.png
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formatting within the `For` loop makes that *very* difficult to read, and therefore, very *easy* to screw up.

If you fix up your indenting like this:

```
Sub Labels_graph_Test()

  Dim Qrts As Series

  Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Q_Graph")
  Set Qrts = ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

  For i = 1 To 4

    With Qrts.Points(i).DataLabel
      If InStr(1, currentcell, "(*") Then
        With Selection.Font.Color = vbRed
      Else
        Selection.Font.Color = vbBlack
      End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

It's really easy to see that you have two `With` blocks that aren't closed out with an `End With`.

Also, you're not using `With` correctly. I believe (off the top of my head, don't quote me on this, you may need to do a bit of additional research). that it should look something like this:

```
    With Qrts.Points(i).DataLabel
      If InStr(1, currentcell, "(*") Then
        .Font.Color = vbRed
      Else
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
      End If
    End With
```

Note that the statement within the `If` and `Else` statements begin with a period (`.`). That tells the compiler to "start looking for this shortened function/method/property at the end of the object that I called out in that `With` statement back there". i.e. it will translate `.Font.Color` to `Qtr.Points(i).DataLabel.Font.Color` which is what you want to set to `vbBlack` or `vbRed`.

**Again**, I'm not 100% certain that's the exact location to go to in order to set the colors - you should be able to find that one fairly easily here on SO, in the MS Docs, or by using the macro recorder to set the color by hand and let it tell you the exact property to set. (Macro Recorder is *excellent* as the lazy man's way of finding those properties. It ***sucks*** at writing nice, readable, efficient, maintainable code.)

`currentcell`: my initial assumption was that this was a variable global to the module or the entire project that contained the text of whatever you wanted to look at. Seems I was wrong (that's what happens when you assume)...

I believe that what you want to replace `currentcell` with would be `Qrts.Points(i).DataLabel.Text` so you can look at the actual label for this particular point. However, you have that `With` statement in there, so you can shorten that to `.Text`. Your `If` statement would look like this:

```
If Left$(.Text, 1) = "(" Then
```

*see "Another thought" section for full details on the rest of the rewrite of this `If` statement.*

Again, I'm not 100% certain that `.Text` is the exact property, but, off the top of my head, I believe that's it. If not, in the Immediate Window of the VBE, you can type `ChartObjects.Points(i).DataLabel.` and the IntelliSense should give you the list of all possible options. Scroll through the list looking for likely candidates. If you're still not sure, do that while the code is running (step through to the `If` statement, then do the above process). If you proceed that with a `?` in the Immediate Window, it will print the value of whatever you're asking for so you can examine it. Note - this is just one of a multitude of ways of figuring this out (MS Docs, SO, Google, etc. are other options).

Another thought: Instead of using the somewhat less readable `InStr` function to check to see if the first character of the string is a left-paren, you can simple do:

```
If Left$(currentcell, 1) = "(" Then
```

I'm not certain about the performance level difference, and it's probably pretty minute, but the mental energy required of the next person to have to maintain this code (potentially future you), will be much lower, thus more maintainable code.

NB: `Left` and `Left$` are nearly identical. However `Left` returns a variant that needs to be implicitly cast to a `string` for the comparison to "(", while `Left$` returns a `string` that doesn't need the implicit cast. It goes a long way toward code that "Does what it says and says what it does".

Comment: What a fantastic explanation and suggestions, I mixed both your and Luuklag answer to come up to a more clean and understandable code. However, I wrote in the answer above the issue I'm facing: all the labels are being colored with black as it's not able to find the parenthesis.  I think that something smarter than _currentcell_ needs to be used. Any idea?

Comment: @MartimOnFire `currentcell`... I _assumed_ (probably incorrectly) that this was some global variable holding the contents of whatever cell you you were looking at. I'm guessing that's not the case... Gimme a couple and I'll update

Comment: @MartimOnFire  You could replace `currentcell` with `.text`

Comment: I thought that was a cell, but with the error that I'm facing I realized that actually it's indeed an object. The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method". To give you more insights: I have this same range in excel, however the graph is linked to a different cell range to uniform the units along another series that is also included in the same graph. Would it be better to verify the cell range and accordingly to that it would color the respective label in the graph ?

Comment: [update] 
It worked with the `.text`  ! I'll update my question and select your answer as correct due the level of detail. 
Thank you so much

Comment: @MartimOnFire it probably didn't work previously because of the various errors you'd had in your original code. I'm glad this got it working for you. No promises, but I think `if .Text(1) = "("` might actually work, too. Either that or `.Text.Characters(1)` - something like that... Something for you to investigate if you feel like learning further.

Comment: @MartimOnFire I can recommend a tool called [RubberDuck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/). It's a very active open source add-in for the VBE that will help with simple things like indenting, subtle things like `Left` vs `Left$` and many many more. It's really helped my coding improve over the last couple of years. Disclaimer: I'm an enthusiastic user and fan, have submitted bug reports (enough to occasionally be named head of QA :) and feature requests and have even contributed a small graphics tweak.

Comment: @FreeMan great recommendation, I didn't know that, I'll use it definitely as I already can see that I'll benefit from using it (avoid newbie mistakes). 
Regarding `Left` and `Left$`, both work, the other 2 suggestions didn't work (some issue with object as well). 
I'm very very grateful for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

There are <strike>two</strike> three problems: (as per comments)

1. As you have text after your `Then` on the same line your `If` statement is considered as a one-liner, and that doesn't need an `End If`. Hence there is an `End If` without an corresponding `If` in your code. See for examples the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement#example)
2. There is a `With` that doesn't have a corresponding `End With`.
3. Your currentcell is not declared and thus holds no value. You are looking for the text of the datalabel. As you are already inside a `With` loop for your Datalabel you can replace `currentcell` with `.Text` to reference the text value of the current Datalabel.

Your code should then look something like: (Untested)

```
For i = 1 To 4

     With Qrts.Points(i).DataLabel

         If InStr(1, currentcell, "(*") Then 
             .Font.Color = vbRed
         Else 
             .Font.Color = vbBlack
         End If   
     End With
Next i
```

Comment: #ThatsWhatISaid but much more concisely. :)

Comment: As FreeMan mentioned, that was very concise and clear. Thank you for your answer. I have an issue with the code now, as the labels are objects, and I'm using the _currentcell_ I guess that it's leading to an issue (isn't finding the parenthesis). What's your opinion?

Comment: Just to be clear that @Freeman point (3.) solved (replacing `currentcell ` by `.Text` ) the issue I was facing. Thank you for it.